# Pygame text not appearing in window

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am implementing text in my code so that I will be tell the user exactly what is happening but there seems to be problems with the text showing on the pygame display especially when I call it.

I have already tried various methods of displaying text in the pygame window and it does not seem to work.

class maze():
     def **init**(self,new):
        self.new = new
        self.walls = []
        self.lab_walls = []
        self.cells = []

```
    a = 0
    v = 0

    for q in range(23):
        for r in range(39):
            deed = q in (0,1,2) and r > 60
            if not deed:
                self.cells.append(cell((a + 8, v, 25,8), (a + 8, v + 33, 25, 8), (a, v + 8, 8 ,25), (a + 33, v + 8, 8, 25)))
            a += 33
        a = 0
        v += 33

    for w in self.cells[0].walls:
        self.lab_walls.append(w)
        self.walls.append(w)

    self.cells[0].view = True

    while len(self.walls) > 0:
        bounds = random.choice(self.walls)
        divcells = []
        for p in self.cells:
            if bounds in p.walls:
                divcells.append(p)

        if len(divcells) > 1 and (not ((divcells[0].view and divcells[1].view) or ((not divcells[0].view) and (not divcells[1].view)))):

            for g in divcells:
                g.walls.remove(bounds)

                if g.view == False:
                    g.view = True

                for o in g.walls:
                    if not o in self.walls:
                        self.walls.append(o)

                    if not o in self.lab_walls:
                        self.lab_walls.append(o)

                if bounds in self.lab_walls:
                    self.lab_walls.remove(bounds)

        self.walls.remove(bounds)

    for j in range(0, 789, 33):
        for i in range(0, 1290, 33):
            self.lab_walls.append((i, j, 8, 8))

 def draw(self, win):
    displaysurf.fill(WHITE)

    for g in self.lab_walls:
        pygame.draw.rect(displaysurf, BLACK, pygame.Rect(g[0], g[1], g[2], g[3]))
    pygame.draw.rect(displaysurf, PURPLE, win)
```

The text is supposed to show on the pygame window but nothing shows apart from the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are rendering the label only in the initial render, but in your main loop you render the background, which basically clears the screen, so you need to render everything again for each frame. Move the line

```
screen.blit(label, (600,600))
```

Before the line

```
pygame.display.flip()
```